# PHP - Notice: Undefined index Formulario Select

Tags: php, undefined

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple procesamiento de un  en PHP y me arroja el siguiente error:

Notice: Undefined index: pago1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\actividadangel2\actividad.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: pago1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\actividadangel2\actividad.php on line 45

```html
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
          <td><img src="001-corn.png"></td>
          <td>Maíz</td>
          <td><input action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" type="number" name="valorneto" placeholder="Introduzca el monto"></td>
          <td>     
            <select id="metodo_de_pago" name="pago1">
              <option value="E">Efectivo</option>
              <option value="T">Tarjeta</option>
            </select>
            
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php
              if ($_POST["pago1"]=="E") 
              {
                $valorneto = ($_POST['valorneto']);
                $sumaE = (int)$valorneto + ((((int)$valorneto * 16))/100); #Nota: Se solventó el problema de "non-numeric value" con (int). 
                echo $sumaE ." " ."Petros";           
              } 
             else {
                if ($_POST["pago1"]=="T") 
                {
                  $valorneto = ($_POST['valorneto']);
                  $sumaT = (int)$valorneto+((((int)$valorneto)*(10))/100);
                  echo $sumaT;
                }
              }         
               if (!empty($_POST['valorneto'])) {
                  echo " ";
                }
            ?>        
          </td> 
        </form> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td style="align-content: center;">
            <input type="submit" name=" operar">           
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Las líneas en cuestión son:

> 38 = if ($_POST["pago1"]=="E")
>   45 = if ($_POST["pago1"]=="T")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en realidad no es un error mas bien seria una notificación o advertencia en este caso "NOTICE", esto se debe a que "$_POST["pago1"]" no está declarado si no hasta despues de enviar el formulario, tienes varias opciones para solucionar esto.

1. Editar `php.ini` del servidor y configurar el `error_reporting` para que no notifique los `NOTICE`:

   `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
   ; Notificar todos los errores excepto los NOTICE`
2. Desactiva los `NOTICE` Al principio de tu archivo, es decir se desactivaran solo en este archivo al momento de ejecutarse. Utilizando la funcion `error_reporting()`

   `<?php 
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // esto al principio de tu archivo`
3. Otra alternativa es ejecutar tu porción de código solamente si el formulario fue enviado.

   `<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
       if ($_POST["pago1"]=="E") { //aqui el resto de tu codigo...`

Comment: Me funcionó desactivando los Notice al principio del archivo. ¡Muchas gracias!